# MySQL and PHP - logical condition grouping of linked entities

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table conditions, which defines some conditions.
I have another table called rules which defines some rules, and each rule can have many conditions. However, the rule must be able to have grouped conditions in this manner:

```
(condition1) && 
(condition2) && 
    (condition3 
    || condition4 
    || 
       (condition6 && 
       condition7)
    ) && 
(condition5)
```

Since this nesting can go as deep as it wants, I can't bind these two tables with a bind table, so I was thinking of actually saving it into the rules table as such:
(condition1)&&(condition2)&&(condition3||condition4||(condition6&&condition7))&&(condition5)
where "condition1" would be the ID of condition 1, etc.

I would then parse this information in PHP, and somehow create a logical check from the entire string.

Is this an OK approach, or is there a better way to do this kind of nested binding withing MySQL? I absolutely need to keep the ability to group conditions in both AND and OR subgroups on a single rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly steer clear of storing your conditions as a string. You'll have to parse that string to use it and if you want to edit an pre-existing conditions (or search for certain conditions etc) you will probably end up tying yourself in knots.

I would certainly store it in some form of tree structure although @tpaksu's solution has a few flaws. I would suggest something along these lines

```
ID  |  Rule_ID   |  Condition_ID    |  Parent   |  Operator |
------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1         |  NULL            | NULL      |  AND      |
2   |  1         |  1               | 1         |  NULL     |
3   |  1         |  2               | 1         |  NULL     |
4   |  1         |  NULL            | 1         |  OR       |
5   |  1         |  3               | 4         |  NULL     |
6   |  1         |  4               | 4         |  NULL     |
7   |  1         |  NULL            | 4         |  AND      |
8   |  1         |  6               | 7         |  NULL     |
9   |  1         |  7               | 7         |  NULL     |
10  |  1         |  5               | 4         |  NULL     |
```

I think this represents the original logical structure you wanted to model. The advantage of this is you can have several branches in your tree where there are conditions at the same level and you can trace which branch each condition belongs to - you don't have to rely on the order of the entries in the table. The parent column refers to the table's main ID column.

You basically have two types of row (which suggests to me you may be able to split this into two tables):

- a row with an operator is a "node" that combines one or more conditions/nodes using one of the two logical operators (but I guess you could use any logical operator). These nodes have no condition_id
- a row with a condition_id represents a single condition (I've numbered them as per your example). These rows have no operators as you can't have an operator on a single operand. I'm not taking into account whether your base conditions do themselves use the same logical operators as you've abstracted that detail in your question.

I'm not sure you need the rule_id as well. In this example, you don't but if you wanted to store meta-info about each rule (e.g. name/label, valid date range etc) you might want to extract that out into a separate table. It might also make it easier to reconstruct the logic in PHP as MySQL doesn't easily handle recursive queries AFAIAA.

Comment: Beautiful. I've analyzed this to a great extent and I love it. I'll give it a go today and tomorrow and report back on how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Still building the logic above it, some new features came into play plus I'm decoupling it as a component so it can be used in other frameworks as well. Should be done and tested in a couple days if I catch a breather

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but it got me on the right track. Sure, done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might have used this structure if I would build something like this,

```
ID  |  Rule_ID   |  Condition_ID    |  Level   |  Operator |
------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1         |  1               | 0        |  AND      |
2   |  1         |  2               | 1        |  OR       |
3   |  1         |  1               | 1        |  OR       |
4   |  1         |  2               | 0        |  NULL     |
```

So it would produce:

condition1 && (condition2 || condition1) || condition2

Ok, here's what I succeeded :

```
<?php

/*(condition1) && 
(condition2) && 
    (condition3 
    || condition4 
    || 
       (condition6 && 
       condition7)
    ) && 
(condition5)

id  | RuleID  | conditionID | level   | operator
-------------------------------------------------
1     1         1             1         AND
2     1         2             1         AND
3     1         3             2         OR
4     1         4             2         OR
5     1         6             3         AND
6     1         7             3         AND
7     1         5             1         NULL

*/

$conditions = array(
    array(),
    array(condition=>"condition1"),
    array(condition=>"condition2"),
    array(condition=>"condition3"),
    array(condition=>"condition4"),
    array(condition=>"condition5"),
    array(condition=>"condition6"),
    array(condition=>"condition7")
);

$rules = array(
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>1,level=>1,operator=>"AND"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>2,level=>1,operator=>"AND"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>3,level=>2,operator=>"OR"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>4,level=>2,operator=>"OR"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>6,level=>3,operator=>"AND"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>7,level=>3,operator=>"AND"),
    array(RuleID=>1,conditionID=>5,level=>1,operator=>null)
);

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($conditions);
//print_r($rules);


//mocking mysql ruleID filter with array_filter()
$firstrule = array_filter($rules,function($element){return ($element["RuleID"]==1);});

var_dump($firstrule);

$level = 1;
$condition_count = count($firstrule);
foreach($firstrule as $key=>$condition){

    $new_level = $condition["level"];
    $next_level = $firstrule[$key+1]["level"];
    $prev_op = $firstrule[$key-1]["operator"];

    if($new_level!=$level){
        if($new_level>$level){
            echo str_repeat("(",$new_level-$level);
            if($condition_count > $key && $next_level < $new_level){
                echo $conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"];
            }else{
                echo $conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"].getOperator($condition["operator"]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($condition_count > $key && $next_level < $new_level){
                echo str_repeat(")",$level-$new_level);
                echo getOperator($prev_op).$conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"] ;
            }else{
                echo str_repeat(")",$level-$new_level);
                echo $conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"] ;
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($condition_count > $key && $next_level < $new_level){        
            echo $conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"];
        }else{      
            echo $conditions[$condition["conditionID"]]["condition"].getOperator($condition["operator"]);
        }

    }
    $level = $new_level;
}

function getOperator($op){
    switch($op){
        case "AND": return "&&";
        case "OR" : return "||";
        case null : return "";
        default   : return "";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Good idea, but I don't see how you would build my example with this structure. Could you demonstrate please?

Comment: and output of this code is : `condition1&&condition2&&(condition3||condition4||(condition6&&condition7))&&condition5`

Comment: Interesting approach. There's some bugs in the demo code is you, after the 2 level 3s, put down one level 2 and then 2 level 3s again, but otherwise impressive. Now I'm thinking whether or not it's overkill to have it like this, but all in all, this is a decent approach, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And I think it's a bit like the query builders like active record is using but they don't have this multi level approach I guess. It's worth checking some of their methods I think.

Comment: I've decided against it after all. This approach makes me completely dependent on the ID order of the definitions, and the structure itself doesn't really become any different than an actual string like condition1&&condition2&&(condition3||condition4||(condition6&&condition7))&&con‌​dition5 because the conditions aren't really grouped - you're just telling the code what to write where and there is no logical coherence. Upon further inspection, this is basically just breaking a string into a table, which seems like overkill, instead of defining logical units. Still, a valiant attempt!

Comment: I just like to challenge myself :)